# Replacing a photo in an existing animation

Tags: image

With Blender 2.78c I added an image bmp on a plane and used it to create an animation.
Now I only want to replace my previous image with a new one and use it to run the same animation as before.
Unfortunately, whatever I do with regard to changing the image with the material, texture and UV editor, the final animation rendering keeps showing the previous image.
Please your assistance. What do I do wrong and what should I do?

Comment: Do you have any strips in the VSE?

Comment: Thank you cegaton for your helpful reply. Indeed I forgot the previous stripe.  As soon as erased it the problem's solved. Thanks a lot.